# заменить строки в одном текстовом файле информацией из второго

Tags: python, bash, perl, cmd, shell

Именются 2 гигантских текстовых файла.

file1.txt (3,6 Гб) содержит только одну колонку (в том числе много дубликатов):

```
123456
123456
123456
абвгд
абвгд
01щенок
01щенок
01щенок
01щенок
01щенок
a0125uß
a0125uß
```

file2.txt (1,5 ГБ) содержит ту же колонку, но без дубликатов плюс вторую колонку.

```
123456:artur
абвгд:sergey
01щенок:max
a0125uß:stasik
```

Задача: сравнить первые колонки в обеих  файлах и заменить одинаковые строки в первом файле, строками из второй колонки второго файла, чтобы получилось следующее (дубликаты в первом файле должны остаться):

```
artur
artur
artur
sergey
sergey
max
max
max
max
stasik
stasik
```

У меня есть такой код:

```
import io
STRFILE1 = 'file1.txt'
STRFILE2 = 'file2.txt'
STRFILERESULT = 'result.txt'
fIN = open(STRFILE1,'r')
strContent = fIN.read()
fIN.close()

with open(STRFILE2,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        mapping = line.split(":",1)
        strContent = strContent.replace(mapping[0],mapping[1].rstrip("\n"))

fOUT = open(STRFILERESULT,'w')
fOUT.write(strContent)
fOUT.close()
```

но он работает вечно с таким объёмом строк (102.600.000 - файл 1 и 50.000.000 - файл 2). Как можно ускоритъ процесс обработки?

Comment: *Как можно ускоритъ процесс обработки?* Загнать это всё в БД и получить результат.

Comment: А без БД никак?

Comment: Ну почему? очень даже как... но СУБД специально придуманы в т.ч. и для такого типа задач, и создают их люди неглупые - ты правда надеешься, что сможешь сделать лучше?

Comment: У меня нет СУБД, а есть Emeditor, Python for Windows, Perl for Windows, Ubuntu for Windows, cmd. Данная задача возникает у меня от силы раз в квартал, а потому мне не хочется возиться ешё и с БД. Можеет кто хотя бы подскажет как выводить строки предварительно в темп-файл, чтобы я хотя бы мог отслеживатъ скорость и примерно подсчитатъ оставшееся время? Скрип обрабатывает 2 файла с 100.000 строк в течение 5 минут, а с этими огромными работает уже 4 дня. Я сам в Питоне не в зуб, скрипт написала коллега, но она увы в декрете.

Comment: в питоне по умолчанию доступен sqlite -- `import sqlite3`

Comment: И? Ладно, просто поделю файлы и через batch прогоню. Так для меня понятнее и без геммороя. Тем не менее спасибо всем ответившим!

Comment: Вопрос - данные в реальных файлах упорядочены как в примере или нет?

Comment: Да, дубликаты стоят рядом друг с другом

Comment: Ваши комменты не видны были получателям, т.к. нужно указывать ник через @, например @gil9red. Ник можно не указывать, если обращаться к автору ответа или вопроса

Comment: у вас result.txt неверный. Должно быть 5 max, так как 01щенок 5 раз повторяется

Comment: Второй файл загнать в memcached, а по первому просто один раз пройтись построчно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на python, то можно так:

```
def story_key():
    with open('te2', 'r') as f2:
        my_key = {i.split(':')[0]: i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in f2}
    return my_key

all_key = story_key()

def read_small(f_object, f_size=1024):
    while True:
        data = f_object.read(f_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

def f_write():
    with open('te1') as f1:
        with open('te3', 'a') as f3:

            for i in read_small(f1):
                a = [all_key[j] + '\n' for j in i.split('\n') if j]
                f3.write(''.join(a))

f_write()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Линукс мне более подходит.

Comment: my_key слишком тяжел получится, 1.5Gb файл, к томуже f_write свалится на ошибку, если длина любой линии в первой файле, будет больше чем f_size. И двойной split(':') в story_key, излишен

Answer (score 6):

> Как можно ускоритъ процесс обработки?

например, можно воспользоваться не языком программирования, а самыми обыкновенными [*gnu*-утилитами *join*, *sort*, *cut*, *nl*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Coreutils). с большой долей вероятности это будет работать быстрее, нежели манипуляции со «словарями», или, тем более, базой данных (время на создание индекса, скорее всего, значительно превысит время, за которое отработают предлагаемые утилиты).

если порядок строк не важен, то замена будет произведена довольно быстро:

```
$ join -t : -o 2.2 <(sort файл1) <(sort файл2)
max
max
max
max
max
artur
artur
artur
stasik
stasik
sergey
sergey
```

если порядок важен, вычислений понадобится значительно больше. что-нибудь в этом духе:

```
$ join -t : -1 2 -o 1.1,2.2 <(nl -n rz -s ':' файл1 | sort -t ':' -k 2) <(sort файл2) | sort -n | cut -d : -f 2
artur
artur
artur
sergey
sergey
max
max
max
max
max
stasik
stasik
```

Comment: То, что надо!!! Спасибо!!!! 2 Минуты - всё готово!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш скрипт медленный потому что вы для каждого уникального значения создаёте 3.6GB строчку заново.

Предполагая что все дубликаты подряд идут и порядок уникальных значений одинаковый в обоих файлах, можно читать файл с заменами и писать их в выходной файл столько раз, сколько текущий ключ повторяется в файле с дубликатами:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import groupby

with open('file1.txt', 'rb') as dups_file, \
     open('file2.txt', 'rb') as replacements_file, \
     open('result.txt', 'wb') as output_file:
    groups = groupby(dups_file)
    for line in replacements_file:
        key, value = line.split(b':')  
        dupe_key, dupes = next(groups)
        assert key == dupe_key.rstrip(), (key, dupe_key)
        for _ in dupes:
            output_file.write(value)
```

Чтобы сделать код более устойчивым к неправильному вводу, в зависимости от вашей ситуации, добавьте try/except и пропускайте соответствующие строки. Для ожидаемого ввода, код как есть работает.

Этот код читает по одной строчке из каждого файла за раз (минимально памяти требует O(1)).

Использование `'b'` режима предполагает, что текст в файлах закодирован используя одинаковые кодировки.

Answer (score 1):

Я не зря задавал вопрос про упорядоченность повторяющихся данных. Эту мысль подхватил @[jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) и прислал практически оптимальное решение с учетом регулярности данных.
Добавлю только, что основное время уходит на обработку строки:

```
strContent = strContent.replace(mapping[0],mapping[1].rstrip("\n"))
```

которую вы постоянно держите "в памяти". Чтобы было понятно  -  сколько примерно времени уходит на "ворочанье" в памяти strContent приведу близкий по смыслу код. Первый пример - почти как у вас - "все в одно":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import time
fw = open('fileDict.txt',"w", buffering=4096, encoding='utf-8')

out_text = ''
prefix = "key"
t_start = time()
for i in range(10000000):
    out_text += prefix+str(i)+":" + str(i)+ '\n' 

fw.write(out_text)    
t_end = time()

fw.close()
print('work_time=', t_end  - t_start )

# results:
#  without buffering in line #4
#  1 000 000    time    27.8 sec
# 10 000 000    time  3403.8 sec 
#  with buffering in line #4
#  1 000 000    time    26.8 sec
# 10 000 000    time  3350.8 sec
```

второй вариант - запхнем кусочками в список:

```
from time import time
fw = open('fileDict.txt',"w",encoding='utf-8')

out_text = ''
prefix = "key"
out_list = []
t_start = time()
for i in range(10000000):
    out_list.append( prefix+str(i)+":" + str(i)+ '\n' )
t_middle =  time()

for line in out_list:
    fw.write(line)        
t_end = time()

fw.close()

print('work_time=', t_end  - t_start, "parsing time:", t_middle-t_start, \
      " + writing_time: ", t_end  - t_middle )

# results:
#  1 000 000    time    2.2 sec
# 10 000 000    time   21.8 sec
```

печать для 1 000 000:
work_time= 2.2221806049346924 parsing time: 1.2595593929290771  + writing_time:  0.9626212120056152

печать для 10 000 000:
work_time= 21.796194791793823 parsing time: 12.18700361251831  + writing_time:  9.609191179275513

Из чего следует, что представление обрабатываемых данных вашим программистом было выбрано не лучшим образом. Действительно разница в обработке как 3340 к 12 ... на построении данных для файла в 10 млн строк размером почти 200Мб